# How to create an event when pressing on a leaflet popup in R?

Tags: r, maps, shiny, leaflet, rstudio

I would like to make the tabPanel change in Shiny when I click on a Leaflet polygon. I have a couple of ideas on how to do this, but I can't find the information I need to implement them. I have the leaflet in a tabPanel, but I would like to switch to another tab when a polygon is clicked on.

```
    leaflet(llmap) %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      addPolygons(stroke = F,
                  fillOpacity = .8,
                  smoothFactor = .5,
                  color=~pal(x),
                  popup = pop)
```

I thought of making `popup=updateTabsetPanel(session="New Tab")`, but that doesn't work. My other idea is to call `updateTabsetPanel(session="New Tab")` anytime the user clicks on a new polygon, but I don't know what event I would need to return to let it know that a new polygon was clicked or even if a new popup popped up. Does anyone know this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's an example of a reactive function that updates when you click a polygon:

```
output$myMap <- renderLeaflet({
    map_out() #this is just a function that returns a leaflet map
  })


output$MyGraph <- renderPlot({  
    event <- input$myMap_shape_click #Critical Line!!!

    ... #Code to run here

    GraphData <- GraphData[event$id] # subsetting example

    }
  })
```

A few things to note here:

1. the `input$myMap_shape_click` changes based on what you call your map above. I called it `myMap`, so the structure is as shown. If you used `output$YourMap` to initialize, the click would be called with `input$YourMap_shape_click`
2. the id of the polygon that you click on can be accessed with `event$id`. This can be really useful for subsetting + graphing based on a polygon that is clicked. Also accessible are `event$lat` and `event$lng`
3. the `renderPlot` can be any reactive function. If its not tied to a specific output, you can just use `observe` as below. This way, your code will run anytime a polygon is clicked. This is because the value of `input$myMap_shape_click` changes every time you click.

I haven't used `updateTabsetPanel` before, but I'd imagine this will work:

```
observe({

  event <- input$myMap_shape_click

  updateTabsetPanel(session, "inTabset", selected = event$id)

})
```

which would switch the tab to a panel with the same id as the polygon you clicked.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer! I encountered exactly the same problem as mentionned above and reported it to the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50334935/use-r-leaflet-actionlink-button-within-addpolygons-function). I think there is still something I don't understand concerning shape clik events on leaflet, could someone help me?